# Lightweight (graphical) image editor

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I am looking for a lightweight image editor for linux (not gimp). I need only one simple feature, namely to draw straight lines (with adjustable thickness) over an image. It should be possible to move, resize and rotate the lines after drawing them.

Answer (score 10):

You should try [pinta](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pinta) [image: Install pinta]. It is pretty lightweight and it is quite rich in features.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I move, resize and rotate lines after drawing them?

Comment: I don't think it can move or rotate links after drawing them yet. I answered before your update.. :/

Comment: The application is really lightweight and has enough features, but the **documentation** is regrettably **poor** :-\

Answer (score 3):

You should try [shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pinta). You can draw straight lines, even if there is not on a picture  took by shutter.

Comment: On my non-gnome ubuntu, it pulls in a bunch of libraries. I'd rather go with `pinta`

Comment: `shutter` depends on `libgnome`, but `pinta` depends on  `libmono`, so I'd say it's a wash in terms of library dependencies...